# Does every $*$-algebra have a state that annihilates a given left ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a $*$-algebra (not C* algebra). Then for all states $\omega$
$$I := \{a\in\mathfrak{A} \ | \ \omega(a^\dagger a) = 0\}$$
is a left ideal.

Is the converse true? Given a left ideal $I\subseteq\mathfrak{A}$, is there a state $\omega$ so that $I = \{a\in\mathfrak{A} \ | \ \omega(a^\dagger a) = 0\}$ or $I \subseteq \{a\in\mathfrak{A} \ | \ \omega(a^\dagger a) = 0\}$?

For C* algebras I think it is true if the left ideal $I$ is closed, by using Hahn-Banach theorem.